# Dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10. Where to put the grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, samsung

can anyone help me with getting this to work ?

1. I have two physical SSD drives(Samsung and Kingston) - on the Samsung one I have Windows 8 installed , Kingston is free and formatted and It's dedicated to Ubuntu 13.10 .
2. I tried a whole bunch of youtube guides on how to install both OSs, but didn't find what I need .
3. Is it possible at all to install Ubuntu on a completely different physical drive ( which has got nothing to do with the drive where Windows is already installed) and to make the system prompt me to choose between Windows and Ubuntu ?
4. I Tried installing the grub loader on to the Samsung drive and Ubuntu files on to Kingston drive and nothing happens , system just redirects me to Windows and never asks what OS to be chosen .

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible at all to install Ubuntu on a completely different physical drive ( which has got nothing to do with the drive where Windows is already installed) and to make the system prompt me to choose between Windows and Ubuntu ?"

**Yes!**

Install Grub2 on the Ubuntu (Kingston) drive and change the boot order in your BIOS to The Kingston (Ubuntu) drive.

Grub2 should find your Windows 8 installation on the Samsung drive and add it to the menu options for you.